# ScardTransmit Blocks in OS X El Capitan 10.11

Tags: macos, smartcard, pkcs#11

I have developed a PKCS#11 library and working fine in OS-X 10.10.5 Yosemite, but when I am loading the same library in OS-X El Capitan 10.11 it's getting blocked at ScardTransmit function.

I have tried with both protocols ( SCARD_PCI_T0 and SCARD_PCI_T1 ) but it's always blocking. I am sending proper APDU commands to the card as well.

Do we have any issues with ScardTransmit API in this particular (Capitan 10.11) Mac version?

Comment: Earlier i thought like i had problem with ScardConnect but actually problem is with ScardTransmit. It's getting blocked at ScradTransmit . Please help.